# Making a body move along with the camera

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm currently making a basic 2d platformer in libGdx, and I want to check when the player isn't within the camera boundaries and, if so, I want to make him restart the level.

The camera moves constantly at the speed of 0.5 y coordinates per tick, so will have to use setLinearVelocity on a kinematic body or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one Solution

You can use

```
camera.position.x
```

to get the current position of your camera.
Then you compare the camera position to the character's position

```
if(camera.position.x - distance_left_From_The_Center_of_Your_Screen < character.position) {
camera.translate(-0.5, 0)
}
```

And this should move your camera

Comment: But how do I get the distance from the center? Also, the character's getPosition() doesn't seem to return values in pixels...